# How to convert Boolean values to Yes or No in Extjs Combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, boolean

I am trying to display yes or no values instead of true or false in Extjs Combo box I am not sure which listener to use or any other way to do it. appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static store like this:

```
Ext.define('MyYesNoStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  fields: [ 'id', 'name' ],
  data: [
    { id: false, name: 'No' },
    { id: true, name: 'Yes' }
  ]
})
```

And then just use this store in your Combobox. Note that if you want to do similar thing in grid - there are special properties 'trueText', 'falseText' in the Boolean column.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also specify the **displayField** and **valueField** properties in your combo box.

Full working example of a combo + yes/no store

```
{
   xtype: 'combo',
   valueField: 'id',
   displayField: 'name',
   store: new Ext.data.Store({
      fields: [ 'id', 'name' ],
      data: [
             { id: false, name: 'No' },
             { id: true, name: 'Yes' }
           ]
   })
```

},

If you want to use it in a grid you can also specify a renderer:

```
 renderer: function (value) {
     return value == false ? 'No' : 'Yes';
 }
```